# Resample in pandas: set starting value for time

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to sort a dataframe and count the number of values (rows) which fall into an hour intervall. My dataframe is named col_times and looks like this:

[image]

I then use `col_times.set_index('date_time').resample(rule = 'H')['Uhrzeit'].count()` to count how many values are in each hour. This starts at 14:00:00 because there is now value before it, the earliest time is 14:57:07. However, I need to start counting at 10:00:00 because of the logic I have and that I need to apply this on various dataframes, I need to see that there is no value between 10:00:00 and 10:59:59. How do I set the resample function do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to append new row with date starts from `10:00`:

```
col_times = col_times.set_index('date_time')
date = pd.to_datetime(col_times.index.min().replace(hour=10, minute=0))
col_times.loc[date] = np.nan
print (col_times)
                          Datum   Uhrzeit
date_time                                
2017-10-16 14:57:07  16.10.2017  14:57:07
2017-10-16 14:57:49  16.10.2017  14:57:49
2017-10-16 14:57:57  16.10.2017  14:57:57
2017-10-16 14:58:11  16.10.2017  14:58:11
2017-10-16 14:58:21  16.10.2017  14:58:21
2017-10-16 10:00:07         NaN       NaN

df = col_times.resample(rule = 'H')['Uhrzeit'].count()
print (df)
date_time
2017-10-16 10:00:00    0
2017-10-16 11:00:00    0
2017-10-16 12:00:00    0
2017-10-16 13:00:00    0
2017-10-16 14:00:00    5
Freq: H, Name: Uhrzeit, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Awesome, as always the simplest solutions are the best ones.Thank you. One question: do I need numpy to create the `NaN` values?